# How do I save an image url from Firebase Storage to Firebase realtime data base, the image from my device

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have been trying to save the url to the firebase realtime database here is my code

```
Uri  uri = data.getData();
        StorageReference filePath = 
mStorage.child("Photos").child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid());

        filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(ManageActivity.this, "Image upload 
 successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                profile_image_url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                driver.child("profile image").setValue(profile_image_url);
```

the logcat shows that its a stack over flow error,  here is the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user.drivergeofire, PID: 6758
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.<init>(HashMap.java:836)
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator.<init>(HashMap.java:836)
    at java.util.HashMap.newValueIterator(HashMap.java:908)
    at java.util.HashMap$Values.iterator(HashMap.java:936)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzas(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
```

my research on StackOverflow erros state that it is cause by having may views, I don't have any there.
Your assistance will be veery much appreciated

Comment: You mean, without downloading the image? Making the Firebase download for you and save at the `Storage`?

Comment: yes, I just to store the link, of the image, so other devices can download it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get tue URL from the saved file use:

```
mStorage.child("Photos").child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).getDownloadUrl().getResult();
```

Comment: I added a new part, the image is coming from my device, why would I download it again

Comment: I updated the answer, that solution suits your problem?